# Javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar

I have following javascript function

```
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"datafield",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
    };


<input name="fromdate" type="text" id="datafield"  /> 

<input name="todate" type="text" id="datafield"  />
```

and when i click fromdate text field datepicker shows, when i click todate text field datepicker not display due to same ID ,how it overcomes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have rightly identified the issues is with repeating ID.

Change your Code to as follows to use different ID for each textbox.

```
  window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"fromdate",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
                        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"todate",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
    };


<input name="fromdate" type="text" id="fromdate"  /> 

<input name="todate" type="text" id="todate"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually have two elements with the same ID, it's invalid. Either change your code to work from a class name, or change the ID of the second datepicker input (e.g. to datafield2) and add another line in your javascript:

```
new JsDatePick({
  useMode:2,
  target:"datafield2",
  dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
});
```

Comment: No, it's a single line of code spread out over 5 lines for readability. And so what if it's a library? Does this library magically overwrite the rules for CSS ids?

Comment: No, but from the experience he has it doesn't looks like he is experienced enough to change the code of the library.
And I'm with you about changing the id's and adding the more than one lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"fromdate",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"todate",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
    };


<input name="fromdate" type="text" id="fromdate"  /> 

<input name="todate" type="text" id="todate"  />
```

id replacement takes one time if 2 similar id name in same page

Answer (score 0):

why not just use [jquery ui's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)? then use

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

where a class of `datepicker` has been added to each textbox

```
<input name="fromdate" type="text" id="fromdate" class="datepicker"/> 
<input name="todate" type="text" id="todate" class="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: @Krishna what? do you realize that this answer and question are 2 years 2 months 14 days old? Try asking a new question.

Comment: okey i am asking new Question but its related to this i will post link here to in few hours okey.

Comment: here My question is please check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368400/datepicker-is-not-function-error-in-console and give me reply if u find something helpful.