# use 3 jquery datepicker in 3 differnet html form in single page

Tags: php, html, datepicker

I am using 3 registration forms in a single page with separate form and submit button for all 3 forms. In all 3 forms there is a date column. For this I am using JQuery date picker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
};
</script>
```

and in HTML form field for date

```
<input type="text" size="12" name="date" id="inputField" />
```

Now, I want to apply this type of date picker for all forms, but when I try, only 1 date picker is working. I have tried also with changing field id, but all stuff is not working and now I cannot change the date picker because I have already done its use in database and in some query also.

Comment: An `Id` must be unique, use `class = "inputField"` in all date inputs or use different `ID`'s for all (if necessary).

Comment: i have tried with class but its show no effect..i tried also with different id but its not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique, and from [the documentation I found](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php) for your Calendar script seems that it doesn't accept classes, so the simplest way is to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField1",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField2",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField3",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="12" name="date" id="inputField1" />
...
<input type="text" size="12" name="date" id="inputField2" />
...
<input type="text" size="12" name="date" id="inputField3" />
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated when there are many input fields to be matched. I would opt for a way to select via regualar expression instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16615853/457268

Comment: @k0pernikus it was actually *the simplest way*. In terms of performance and efficiency, I'ld simply query elements by a custom CSS class instead of matching all the input IDs by regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is found here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486261/2394152

> You can't actually have two elements with the same ID, it's invalid.
>   Either change your code to work from a class name, or change the ID of
>   the second datepicker input (e.g. to datafield2) and add another line
>   in your javascript:
>
> ```
> new JsDatePick({   useMode:2,   target:"datafield2",   dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y" });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using classes or manually instanciating `JsDatePicker`, you also could select for matching IDs of the inputField by regular expression using the `$.filter` method.

```
(function($, JsDatePick){
    var $inputFields = $("input").filter(function(){
        return this.id.match(/^inputField\d+$/);
    });

    $.each($inputFields, function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:this.id,
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        });
    });
})(jQuery, JsDatePick);
```

The `^` marks the start of the string, the `inputField` is from your IDs, and the `\d+` part allows it to be followed by for any number and `$` marks the end of the string.