# $(..)DatePicker is not function Error in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, datepicker

[image]this is my child jsp which will be replaced into the Master page see this whole code
`

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.angelcam.dao.UserMethod"%>
<%@page import="com.angelcam.domain.UserWS"%>



<%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"
            + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
            + path + "/";
%>
<%
    System.out.println("view details page called *****  ");
    System.out.println("view details page called *****  ");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    List<UserWS> list = new UserMethod().getUser(id);

    UserWS userWS = list.get(0);
%>


<link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jtabber.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angelcamapp.js">
</script>

-->
<!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>


<form name="updateuser" action="UpdateUser" method="post" onsubmit="">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=request.getParameter("id")%>">

    <div id="table">
        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                First Name
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"
                    value="<%=userWS.getFirstname()%>" class="inputtext" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Last Name
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="inputtext"
                    value="<%=userWS.getLastname()%>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Email
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <input type="text" readonly name="email" id="email"
                    class="inputtext" value="<%=userWS.getEmail()%>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                DOB
            </div>
            <div id="col2">

                <input type="text" id="datepicker" />

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Gender
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <%
                    if (userWS.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("Male")) {
                %>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Male" id="Male"
                    checked="checked" />
                Male
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Female" id="Female" />
                Female
                <%
                    } else {
                %>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Male" id="Male" />
                Male
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Female" id="Female"
                    checked="checked" />
                Female

                <%
                    }
                %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Password
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="inputtext"
                    value="<%=userWS.getPassword()%>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Confirm Password
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <input type="text" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"
                    class="inputtext" value="<%=userWS.getPassword()%>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                Status
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <%
                    if (userWS.isActiveflag()) {
                %>
                <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" checked="checked" />

                <%
                    } else {
                %>
                <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" />
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="row">
            <div id="col1">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <input type="submit" id="button" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
`![enter image description here][2]Hello i am using one Java Script date picker and i am using Ajax too in that. means to Replace Div into Master page.

Here i am using one Java Script Calender Control into the Child Jsp means which is Replacing threw Ajax into the Master Page here my Code is.

    <html>
       <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
       </script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
      </script>

      <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    </script>


      </head>

    <body>
    <div id="row">
                <div id="col1">
                    DOB
                </div>
                <div id="col2">

                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />

                </div>
            </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

i Tried to do that in master page too but its giving same error. Means there is problem with Parent page and child page.
there could be conflict error bcoz i am using other JavaScript library too so i dont know what is really problem is.
because i tried it separate and its working fine.
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you in advance for your Help.

Comment: If you're using anther JavaScript library (maybe interfering with jQuery), try using `jQuery(function ($) {` as your first line.

Comment: ya i tried it but now i am getting this much errors. like this Timestamp: Wednesday 04 December 2013 12:01:07  IST
Warning: Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
Line: 1175

Comment: as i put there is much error that i am getting.

Comment: That's not an error - it specifically says "Warning". It's just saying your browser ignored a specific CSS value for `filter` because your browser didn't know/recognize how to use it...and is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the noConlict option? [jQuery.noConflict Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: for sure let me attach that codes with that so u can have idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(function() {
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It works but now i m getting bunch of error for the CSS and Jquery.. :(

Comment: i have updated my Error screen shot so please see it and suggest me changes.

Comment: Looks like the problem is solved then. Can't help you much with CSS errors but i am pretty sure the CSS community will be able to help you out with this. Just post a separate question regarding this.